# Does android create connections for each http request?

Tags: android, webview

To show a website, you need to fetch html + multiple js/css files.

Does android open connection for each file (URI)?

I'm about to do it (opening connection for each file) and want to know if this is absurdly stupid.

What I want to eventually do is to cache js/css files myself (I'm considering inside `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` )

I tried to see how android itself does it by breaking at the `shouldInterceptRequest` function, but I couldn't find much more info from there.

Comment: "Does android open connection for each file (URI)?" -- if you are referring to inside `WebView`, that will be dictated by the version of `WebView` that you are using. Keep-alive support (and SPDY/HTTP2) should be supported today; I don't know how far back the SPDY/HTTP2 support would go. "I'm about to do it (opening connection for each file) and want to know if this is absurdly stupid" -- if you mean that you are going to make HTTP requests yourself outside of `WebView`, choose an HTTP client API that supports keep-alive and SPDY/HTTP2.

Comment: CommonsWare: oh thanks for detailed answer, I'm not very familiar with keep-alive, and wonder if that's applicable to my use case. That is I don't have a determined set of files to fetch. I have to fetch them as request comes in. As I said in the question, I'd like to intercept the request to static files and cache them for later use. I am looking at HttpURLConnection. Should I somehow create the connection and set the keep-alive option and keep it global?

Comment: "I am looking at HttpURLConnection" -- I would recommend something more modern, like OkHttp. "Should I somehow create the connection and set the keep-alive option and keep it global?" -- I do not know why it would need to be "global", though presumably that is a possibility

Comment: oh ok.. I'll look at volley I guess then since I am already using it. It looks like keep-alive is true for all http connection in android by default. I thought I should use global to reuse the (keep-alived) connection. I guess keep-alive part is internally handled by android itself whether `connection` variable is destroyed or not. So all in all, I just need to use whatever modern http library and android will use the same connection for multiple requests by means of keep-alive. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CommonsWare can you make an answer from your comment so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does android open connection for each file (URI)?

If you are referring to inside `WebView`, that will be dictated by the version of `WebView` that you are using. Keep-alive support (and SPDY/HTTP2) should be supported today; I don't know how far back the SPDY/HTTP2 support would go.

> I'm about to do it (opening connection for each file) and want to know if this is absurdly stupid

If you mean that you are going to make HTTP requests yourself outside of `WebView`, choose an HTTP client API that supports keep-alive and SPDY/HTTP2. Note that keep-alive itself only works on non-SSL connections, and you are using SSL (right? *right?!?*), so SPDY/HTTP2 support is more critical. [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) offers this, to the point where `HttpUrlConnection` on Android 4.4+ is actually using OkHttp under the covers. Other HTTP client libraries may offer it as well.